# Private, protected: свойства при преобразовании объекта в массив

Tags: массивы, php

**Преобразование в массив** [Массивы php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.array.php)

> **к закрытым полям класса (private) спереди будет дописано имя класса; к
> защищенным полям класса (protected)
> спереди будет добавлен символ '*'. Эти
> добавленные значения с обоих сторон
> также имеют нулевые байты.**

```
class B extends A {
    private $A='as'; 
    public $AA='olive'; 
}

$x = (array)new B();
var_dump($x);

var_dump($x["AA"]);//olive

var_dump($x["A"])//null
```

Теперь я хочу иметь возможность получать значения приватных переменных через доступ к ключу массива.
Подскажите что сдесь поможет.Как обработать массив ,чтобы он не содержал специфических символов в именах ключей?

Еще надумалась оборотная задача-преобразования массива в объект

```
 $arr=array("name"=>"stalin","property"=>"tiran");
$obj = (object) $arr;
```

Как при таком коде задать приватные переменные?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если надо убрать только нулевой байт и звездочку из строки, то:

```
$key = str_replace(array("\0", '*'), "", $key);
```

Если же убрать и название класса, то:

```
$nullPos = strrpos($key, "\0");
if ($nullPos !== FALSE) {
    $key = substr($key, $nullPos+1);
}
```

Обратное преобразование.. посмотрите в сторону [Reflection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php): [ReflectionObject](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionobject.php), [ReflectionProperty](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionproperty.php)

Вы же там не [сериализацию](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.serialize.php) изобретаете?